# Is there any other time service than system time that we can make use?

Tags: datetime, systemtime

I am developing a desktop app and it have an trial period after which application will get expire. Currently I am using system time. Since user can easily change it, I thought its not a good way to follow.

Is there any other time service that is available which I can make use of? I heard something like system clock count or something like that which cannot be easily changed by user. Can anyone put light on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to trust the system clock, you are going to have problems.

Probably your best bet is an [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) or SNTP connection to establish the current time from authoritative time servers outside the organization - but you may easily be blocked by firewalls, etc.

However, that is really overkill; people don't futz with the system clock for long - it is far too much of a nuisance.

Comment: I am creating a offline app, so cant even think of connecting anything outside of the machine. And my bosses are too much teckies and thinks developers can magically create/calculate/evaluate applications properly even if no time source other than system time is available. :(

Comment: In the circumstances you describe, you are stuck with the system clock; there isn't a reliable alternative.  If your managers disagree, ask them to indicate what alternatives they think exist - it is always fair to ask them how to do what they ask (or, if it isn't, it is perhaps time to look elsewhere for a different job).

Answer (score 0):

A DIY solution using SNTP [SNTP time class](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/27-networking/649-sntp-time-class.html)