# what is best way to schedule a reboot?

Tags: c#

I am trying to schedule a reboot programmablly on winxp by using c# 
currently, i program it to add a scheduled task in winxp to reboot in 5 min
however, it does not always work because the machine time maybe changed after restart (there is time server in my environment). so that means the scheduled task time is not accurate, in turn my reboot does not work on expected time.

For example, when i added scheduled reboot task, the machine time is 11:05 am and the reboot the is scheduled to 11:10am. then i joined xp to domain and restart, the time got synced with time server and machine changed to 1:01pm.
in this case, the scheduled task has a time 11:10am on same day, it's past. of course it won't work.

so anybody know any other way to do it?
ps: this program is used before joining xp to domain
and reboot is scheduled because it's 2nd reboot and i need it automatically reboot without user interactions

Comment: Maybe just keep the time in sync and the problem won't occur?

Comment: Why do you use a scheduled task? What about simply use the ´shutdown´ command?

Comment: i cannot keep time synced before join to domain.

Comment: @ZombieHunter  im using shutdown -r -t 0 in scheduled task, but problem is the time

Comment: How about running 'shutdown /r /m localhost /t 300' instead of scheduling a task?

Comment: @John Sauders  it's for brand new machines

Comment: @Matten the reboot has to be scheduled, because i need 2nd reboot without user interaction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in [shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown) command by launching a new process from C#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ShutdownApp
{
    class ShutdownApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process shutDown = new Process();
            int shutdownTimeInSeconds = 600; // this will shutdown in 10 minutes, use DateTime and TimeSpan functions to calculate the exact time you need    
            shutDown.StartInfo.FileName  = "shutdown.exe";
            shutDown.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-r -t {0}", shutdownTimeInSeconds);

            shutDown.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i got this part as well as how to add scheduled tasks in c#, it's just a problem with time i think

Comment: This method will work even if Task Scheduler is not on, or the time changes due to joining a domain, etc.

Comment: yes,  this will reboot, but i need 2nd reboot in 5 mins without user interactions

Comment: Don't add it to scheduled tasks, calculate the time using datetime/timespan, find the days/hours/minutes portion till the time you want, calculate it, and run the process. When you're done, even if the time changes, the timer will still be running in the background.

Comment: So if you need a 2nd reboot in 5 minutes without user interactions, add it to scheduled task on "User Startup" (not time dependent) and give it a -t 300 (or 300 in my shutdownTimeInSeconds), and it will reboot 5 minutes after user startup, regardless if it joins the domain and syncs/changes time.

Comment: you mean i dont have to schedule a reboot task for 2nd reboot?

Comment: Not technically, if you wanted to, you could add your program to startup, and launch your program with an argument, that passes in the amount of seconds to the next reboot (300), so the first time they launch your program with no arguments it adds itself to startup, reboots, and the 2nd time, you launch it with that 300 second argument, it launches the command to reboot 5 minutes later, and pulls itself from startup. But it won't require any user interaction, correct.

Comment: which startup registry should i add command to?? the runonce key only executes when user logs in

Comment: The `Process` object here should be wrapped in a `using` statement

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow @JohnSaunders advice and **force a time synchronization** before you add the scheduled task. You could do this using [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) or SNTP. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930134/is-there-any-other-time-service-than-system-time-that-we-can-make-use).

Comment: but it's for brand new machines, cant really do time sync before it's joined to domain, can we?

Comment: This works if you have authority to update the system clock - it doesn't matter whether you are joined to a domain or not. This is probably overkill though given @BrianDeragon solution.